# Gradle Error when using maven publishing task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am using Gradle version 6.7.1, Currently, in my application I facing an issue with the maven publishing task.

We have kept the publishing task in the central location  Gradle file named ( nexusgradle-1.0.5.gradle)   and importing it via `apply from`

the content of the central location Gradle (nexusgradle-1.0.5.gradle) is the below which contain the information of nexus repo for snapshot and release along with user credentials for pushing artefacts to nexus.

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
   }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'uploader'
                password 'uploaderpassword'
            }
            println 'A message which is logged at QUIET level'
            name 'Nexus_Repo'
            def releasesRepoUrl = 'http://<hostname>/repository/<maven-releases>/'
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = 'http://<hostname>/repository/<maven-snapshots>/'
            url = project.version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}
```

The application Gradle ( child Gradle file) looks like the one below

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens

plugins {
    id 'war'
    // Add git release plugin for versioning snaphots and release builds
    id 'pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release' version '1.10.1'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    // Add Git properties plugin.
    id 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties' version '2.2.0'
    id 'jacoco'
 }

// apply from center location
apply from :'http://<hostaname>/repository/thirdparty/com/mf/nexusgradle/1.0.5/nexusgradle-1.0.5.gradle'






repositories {
        maven {
        url = 'http://<hostname>/repository/groupRepo/'
        }
    jcenter()
    }

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    maxParallelForks = 3

    ignoreFailures = true // to skip test Failures
    testLogging { //logging the test
        exceptionFormat = 'full'
        events "passed", "skipped", "failed"
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = '0.8.3'
}

jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
    reports {
        xml.enabled true //enabling for generate xml for to capture data in sonarqube server
    }
}

// Customize Git properties plugin.
gitProperties {
    // Change date format in git.properties file.
    dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ"
    dateFormatTimeZone = 'GMT'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.1.4.RELEASE'
    // mutliple import below 
}

sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
targetCompatibility = '1.8'

scmVersion {
    repository {
        directory = project.rootProject.file('.')
    }
}

group = 'com.package'
description = 'appname'
project.version = scmVersion.version
project.ext.timestamp = new Date().format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

processResources {
    filter ReplaceTokens, tokens:[BUILD_VERSION: project.version, BUILD_TIMESTAMP: project.ext.timestamp]
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

war {
    enabled = true
}



springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

bootWar {
    archiveClassifier = 'boot'
    mainClassName = 'com.package.appname.SpringBootRunner'
}
```

when I run the Gradle command for publishing

```
gradlew clean build publish
```

**The task will fail as the publishing task will try to push artefacts of the snapshot to the release repo instead of the snapshot repo.**

```
  > Configure project :
A message which is logged at QUIET level

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootBuildInfo

> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :generateGitProperties
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootWar
> Task :war
> Task :assemble
> Task :check
> Task :build
> Task :generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication
> Task :generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
> Task :publishMavenJavaPublicationToNexus_RepoRepository FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToNexus_RepoRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'Nexus_Repo'
   > Could not PUT 'http://<hostname>/repository/maven-releases/com/package/appname/1.0.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 400 from server: Repository version policy: RELEASE does not allow metadata in path: com/package/appname/1.0.9-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

**But if I remove the `apply from:` item and bring the Publishing task to the application Gradle ( child Gradle file)  file it will work fine, the build artefact is pushed to snapshot repo without any issue.**

```
> Configure project :
A message which is logged at the QUIET level

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :bootBuildInfo

> Task :compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :generateGitProperties
> Task :processResources
> Task :classes
> Task :bootWar
> Task :war
> Task :assemble
> Task :check
> Task :build
> Task :generateMetadataFileForMavenJavaPublication
> Task :generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication
> Task :publishMavenJavaPublicationToNexus_RepoRepository
> Task :publish

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 29s
10 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 1 up-to-date
```

**Can someone guide me, what mistake I am making when putting the maven publishing task in a parent Gradle file? why child Gradle cant resolve values from parent properly**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix it by updating the content of the central  Gradle  /parent file  (nexusgradle-1.0.5.gradle) by adding

> afterEvaluate

with the modification, it worked fine.
Is it the correct approach? or is there any better way to do it?

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'


afterEvaluate {project ->
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.web
        }
   }
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username 'uploader'
                password 'uploaderpassword!'
            }
            name 'Nexus_Repo'
              def releasesRepoUrl = 'http://<hostname>/repository/<maven-releases>/'
            def snapshotsRepoUrl = 'http://<hostname>/repository/<maven-snapshots>/'
            url = project.version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT') ? snapshotsRepoUrl : releasesRepoUrl
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hi @gibyalex, could you please help me to resolve the issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77702335/mavencentral-image-previewpublishreleasepublicationtoimagepreviewrepository-fa?noredirect=1#comment136987522_77702335